# Itext , pdf created couldn't be open

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, itext

i wanted to create pdf with Itext , everything works until i've made the runnable jar . Adobe reader shows that message : "Adobe Reader could not open xxx.pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example. it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)." And here is my code :

```
    String ruta = txtruta.getText();
    Document doc = new Document();

    try {
        FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(ruta + ".pdf"); //crear archivo con su ruta

        doc.open();

        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(8); //creacion de una tabla de 8 columnas

        tabla.addCell("Celda 1");// addCell() agrega una celda a la tabla, el cambio de fila ocurre automaticamente al llenar la fila
        tabla.addCell("Celda 2");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 3");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 4");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 5");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 6");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 7");
        tabla.addCell("Celda 8");// aca se completa una fila

        doc.add(tabla);

        doc.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PDF creado correctamente");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a line missing in your code:

```
String ruta = txtruta.getText();
Document doc = new Document();

try {
    FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(ruta + ".pdf"); //crear archivo con su ruta
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, archivo);
    doc.open();

    PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(8); //creacion de una tabla de 8 columnas

    tabla.addCell("Celda 1");// addCell() agrega una celda a la tabla, el cambio de fila ocurre automaticamente al llenar la fila
    tabla.addCell("Celda 2");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 3");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 4");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 5");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 6");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 7");
    tabla.addCell("Celda 8");// aca se completa una fila

    doc.add(tabla);

    doc.close();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PDF creado correctamente");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
}
```

Do you see?

Without `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, archivo);` you're creating a `FileOutputStream`, but nothing is ever written to that stream. It's a file with 0 bytes.

Comment: That doesn't explain *"everything works until i've made the runnable jar"*, though...

Comment: No @mkl , but it's the only answer that can be given based on the information in the question. If the OP had said: *I get a class not found exception,* then we could assume that the dependencies aren't correct in the runnable jar (which is the most likely cause of the problem). However, the OP is doing something very stupid when he writes `catch (Exception e)`; chances are that the output of the `System.out` indeed warns him about missing classes, but since the OP doesn't mention any error, we can't comment on that.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing the same issue that Adobe is not opening pdf files but those pdf files are opening in WPS and google chrome. How can I fix that issue. Can anyone help me?